# Route all traffic through my laptop (using Squid) with Windows

Tags: windows, proxy, route, squid

I have just installed Squid on my laptop and I am successfully blocking all the traffic that I want to block ( websites, protocols etc. ).
But I would like to route all the traffic form my LAN ( have just 2 computers in it - and I use Dlink 502T router - I know, an old one).
Any ideas how can I do this ?

I have found something like this on the web but this is for Linux 
http://www.tuxradar.com/answers/432

Comment: This is off-topic for StackOverflow. Ask your question on ServerFault.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The steps for Windows are basically the same as in the link you posted. You need to:

1. force all traffic to go through your proxy laptop by setting the default gateway on all the the other machines in your LAN. The default gateway setting is under the network interface properties, IP protocol.
2. block direct Internet access from the other machines of the LAN by adding firewall rules in the router.

If you are using DHCP for step 1 you may have to tweak the configuration of the default gateway on the router, or if it is not possible, assign fixed IPs to all machines.

Comment: hmmm... you are right but! I have Squid set up on port 3128 and I think that will not work if I set up my laptop's IP as a default gateway on other computers. Maybe I should try to change Squid's port to 80 then ?

Comment: Yes, you need port 80 with the transparent option.