# How to redirect traffic with Apache and Dlink 524T ?

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect, local-area-network, traffic

I would like to redirect all LAN http traffic to my Apache server (which is located temporarily on my laptop ). The basic idea is that every user who connects to the network and tries to connect to a website will be redirected to my Server's `index.html` (or so ...)
I can access the router.

What options can I use to achieve that ?

Comment: The term you are looking for is "captive portal".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Route all traffic through my laptop (using Squid) with Windows](http://serverfault.com/questions/307454/route-all-traffic-through-my-laptop-using-squid-with-windows)

Comment: @Patryk - how is this question different than when you asked nearly the same thing last April?

Comment: @ErikA I asked then for redirection for proxy and know I would like to set up this 'captive portal' - but I would like also to get some specific instructions on how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is generally referred to as a captive proxy. Whether or not you'll be able to set up one largely depends on the capabilities of your router.